# OVER PARTITION BY MAX Date?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to show only the last date a payment was made. Currently the Query looks at all Transaction amounts that are less than zero (which means they paid) and shows the corresponding date. But I just want to show the last or MAX date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT     RMCUST.CUST_NAME AS 'Customer',
                    SUM(RMDET.TRAN_AMT - RMDET.TRAN_AMT_APPLIED)
                    OVER (PARTITION BY RMCUST.CUST_NAME)
                    AS 'Total Balance',
                    CASE WHEN RMDET.TRAN_AMT < 0
                    THEN MAX(RMDET.TRAN_DATE)   
                    ELSE ''     
                    END
                    AS 'Last Payment'
FROM                RMCUST (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN          RMCUSTZ (NOLOCK) ON RMCUSTZ.CUST_CODE = RMCUST.CUST_CODE
INNER JOIN          RMDET (NOLOCK) ON RMDET.CUST_CODE = RMCUST.CUST_CODE
WHERE               RMCUSTZ.AR_BALANCE !=0
GROUP BY            RMCUST.CUST_NAME,
                    RMDET.TRAN_AMT,
                    RMDET.TRAN_AMT_APPLIED,
                    RMDET.TRAN_DATE
ORDER BY            'Customer'
```

Output:

```
Customer                        Total Balance   Last Payment
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
135 PRIME                       462.66          1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
71 ABOVE                        3617.60         1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
71 ABOVE                        3617.60         2020-01-20 00:00:00.000
71 ABOVE                        3617.60         2020-02-14 00:00:00.000
71 ABOVE                        3617.60         2020-02-20 00:00:00.000
71 ABOVE                        3617.60         2020-02-28 00:00:00.000
ABERNETHYS MUSIC CENTER         1014.60         1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
AC HOTEL                        158.50          1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
AC HOTEL                        158.50          2020-01-03 00:00:00.000
AC HOTEL                        158.50          2020-01-10 00:00:00.000
AC HOTEL                        158.50          2020-01-29 00:00:00.000
AC HOTEL                        158.50          2020-02-04 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: And do you want multiple output lines per customer? (Feels like "no"..)

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: Correct, I don't want to see multiple lines, it works thanks to Caius below!

Comment: first - stop splattering [nolock hints](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) everywhere. And when you think you need to use DISTINCT, you should stop and think. DISTINCT is very often used to cover up a logical flaw. Here it appears you just threw it in without any reason other than as a quick "fix" (which it did not).

Comment: Fair comments thanks. I use nolock everywhere because the report hangs if someone else is changing the data. the distinct I was using when I had more queries that needed one, I forgot to take it out. Thanks though, that makes me think twice about using it,

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a query of the form:

```
SELECT
  CustomerName,
  SUM(tranAmount) as Balance,
  MAX(CASE WHEN TranAmount < 1 THEN TranDate END) as MostRecentPayment
FROM
  table 
GROUP BY 
  CustomerName
```

To provide a per customer summary without the repeated rows